# fs.createWriteStream restarts application running on PM2

Tags: node.js, express, npm, fs, pm2

I am using PM2 to run the node applications and I am facing an issue using `fs.createWriteStream` in the application running on PM2,

the case is as below.

**Case:**

- My application is running on PM2 (e.g. `pm2 start app.js`) - either of the way - fork/cluster mode.
- I am using `fs.createWriteStream` to write in a file, code is as below

  ```
  let myWriteSteram = fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve(publicDir, myCSVFileName))
  ```
- As soon as the script reaches and executes the above line, it immediately restarts the application process.

**Solution:**

- I stopped my application from PM2 and started by using `node app.js` and `fs.createWriteStream` started working as expected.

**Version details:**

- npm: *6.10.2*
- node: *v10.16.0*
- pm2: *2.10.3*

Can someone please explain why PM2 is causing this?

This is just one case that I found, there could be many other cases with the file system when we run the application using PM2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you by any chance using `pm2` with `watch` mode? because if you do, pm2 will restart the process because new file content is detected with `createWriteStream`

Comment: Thanks, Tuan Anh Tran, I just found it, --watch was causing the issue.
However, the file which I am creating was in a directory where I am using .gitignore and that file should not be considered in the watch list I guess.

Comment: The issue was with the --watch, it was watching every file in the directory, so whenever a new file was created it was restarting the application, however, while using nodemon the script continues to executing and not causing any issues,
So to use --watch, I need to use ignore_watch to ignore directories.